# Solr Index replicas on DSE 4.5

Tags: solr, solr4, datastax-enterprise, datastax, solrcloud

I am using DSE4.5 and have 5 node solr cluster.
And have created solr core on one solr node (x) and  able to read data from other solr nodes.But if the x node is down then i cant read the data from other nodes.

As i checked there is no index data for that keyspace in solr.data folder on other nodes except its on the x node.

how do i can replicate solr index  across multiple nodes and read data even first node is down in DSE 4.5?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to set the replication factor for the keyspace to something greater than 1.

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/update_ks_rf_t.html

If doing this on an existing cluster you'll then need to run a "nodetool repair" in order to copy the relevant data between nodes.

Comment: I have RF of 2 on this cluster.Even the node from where i am trying to read data have replicated data but not solr core on that node.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're saying here - but I'm guessing that you're trying to mix node types within a DC.  Every node within the solr DC needs to be configured to run solr.  There should be a core on every solr node automatically.

Answer (score 0):

#### Please ensure that all your nodes in this DC are started as Solr nodes

You should be able to tell using:

```
nodetool status
```

or start them with

```
dse cassandra -s
```

As mentioned in the comments by Nom de plume, as long as you have an RF that is greater than 1 and have successfully run a repair you should be able to take the node down with no impact to your solr queries.

You only have to create the core (using curl) in one of your nodes, the core will propagate across the cluster on it's own and the solr indexes should appear in each node based on that node's c* token range.